# How Centering elements in Pane when FullScreen

Tags: javafx

Hello I have several elemenst such as 2 labels, 1 Textfield and One PassField in a Pane, I Want to center all this elements, When the Windows  Go fullScreen (when Maximizes), what should I do?, any orientation here might be helpful.

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;



public class Main extends Application implements Initializable {




    public void start( Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginScreen.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
            primaryStage.show();




    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

this is my FXML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Pane fx:id="Login" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="545.0" prefWidth="371.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="usuario" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="175.0" text="Usuario" />
      <Label fx:id="contrasena" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="232.0" text="Contraseña" />
      <TextField fx:id="fusuario" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="171.0" />
      <PasswordField fx:id="fcontrasena" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="228.0" />
      <Button fx:id="fboton" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="124.0" layoutY="296.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Login" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) and [`GridPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) would probably be best in this situation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane hgap="5.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="usuario" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Usuario" />
            <Label fx:id="contrasena" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Contraseña" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="fusuario" alignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="fcontrasena" alignment="TOP_CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Button fx:id="fboton" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Login" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

[`Full Example`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm#CIHHGHJJ).

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is totally wrong. 1. You should not use a Pane. Use one or more of the layout panes which best fits your needs like BorderPane or AnchorPane together with a HBox or VBox maybe. 2. You should not try to do any absolute positioning. Leave the layout to the layout panes instead. For an introduction have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm